# How can I make AdvancedDataGridRenderProviderer render an ArrayCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[Bindable]
public class MyRecord implements ValueObject
{

    public var recall_id:int;
    public var recall_type:String;
    public var selected:Boolean = false;
    public var qty:Number;
    public var curr_qty:Number;
    public var due_date:String;
    public var status:String;
    public var comments:String;
    public var groupedTrades:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I stuff a bunch of those in an ArrayCollection and then I use this as a dataProvider for an AdvancedDataGrid:

```
<mx:dataProvider>       

                                <mx:HierarchicalData 
                                    source="{model.recalls}"
                                    childrenField="groupedTrades"/>      

                            </mx:dataProvider>
```

I have an AdvancedDataGridRenderProvider that I want to display my 'groupedtrades':

```
<mx:rendererProviders>

                                <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider 
                                    depth="2" 
                                    columnIndex="1" 
                                    renderer="com.controls.GroupedTradesGrid"
                                    columnSpan="0"/>

                            </mx:rendererProviders>
```

In this renderProvider I override the set data function to set the dataProvider:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            // If using the array data source, use this instead:
            trades_dg.dataProvider = value;
        }
```

The problem is that my renderProvider's method is invoked for every record in the dataProvider of the ADG it is part of. This amounts to a brand new DataGrid for each trade in groupedTrades.

How do I resolve this? I'm perplexed.

Thanks for any helpful tips, and Happy Thanksgiving!

UPDATE: I just found some hardcoded array from a blog that is doing what I want; a DataGrid as a renderProvider of an AdvancedDataGrid.

```
private var masterData:Array = [
        { OrderId: 10248, CustomerId:"WILMK", EmployeeId:5, OrderDate:"1-Feb-2007", 
        children:[
                [
                    {ProductId:11, ProductName:"Quesbo Cabrales", UnitPrice:14, Quantity:12, Discount:0, Price:168},
                    {ProductId:42, ProductName:"Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee", UnitPrice:9.8, Quantity:10, Discount:0, Price:98},
                    {ProductId:42, ProductName:"Mozzarella di Giovanni", UnitPrice:34.8, Quantity:5, Discount:0, Price:174}
                ]
                ]}
             ]
         ]}
```

This is from this blog: http://techrays.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/advanced-datagrid-as-an-item-renderer-within-an-advanced-datagrid/#comment-1511

When I debug my collection (recalls is the arraycollection i use) as it is returned from the server I am seeing something like this:

> recalls[0] - RecallRecord object
>   - prop
>   - prop
>   - groupedTrades - ArrayCollection that I want to use as DP for renderProvider
>   groupedTrades[0] - Generic Object
>   groupedTrades[1] - Generic object

I fail to see the difference between the hardcoded version from the blog that works and the data I'm using from my service. What am I missing?

thank you!

Comment: It just seems so strange that if I hardcode my hierarchical data everything works just fine but when I switch to using an array collection of objects it doesn't work at all. What is the difference? Did the way that I write the 'MyRecord' object not properly show a hierarchical data structure?

Comment: Do I need to create a custom data descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

It turns out that the problem was how I assigned the values to 'groupedTrades' when the server responded. I was doing it totally wrong: I was doing a direct assignment instead of adding the ArrayCollection as an element to the 'groupedTrades' ArrayCollection.

I was doing this:

```
for ( var i:int=0;i<result.length;i++ ){
                var item:Object = result[i];

                var recall:RecallRecord       = new RecallRecord();
                recall.counterparty_shortcode = item.counterparty_shortcode;
                recall.comments               = item.comments;
                recall.curr_qty               = item.curr_qty;
                recall.div_percent            = item.div_percent;
                recall.due_date               = df.format( item.due_date );
                recall.qty                    = item.qty;
                recall.rebate_rate            = item.rebate_rate;
                recall.recall_id              = item.recall_id;
                recall.recall_type            = item.recall_type;
                recall.sedol                  = item.sedol;
                recall.status                 = item.status;
                recall.ticker                 = item.ticker;
                recall.groupedTrades          = item.groupedTrades;


                model.recalls.addItem( recall );
            }
```

Instead of this:

```
for ( var i:int=0;i<result.length;i++ ){
                var item:Object = result[i];

                var recall:RecallRecord       = new RecallRecord();
                recall.counterparty_shortcode = item.counterparty_shortcode;
                recall.comments               = item.comments;
                recall.curr_qty               = item.curr_qty;
                recall.div_percent            = item.div_percent;
                recall.due_date               = df.format( item.due_date );
                recall.qty                    = item.qty;
                recall.rebate_rate            = item.rebate_rate;
                recall.recall_id              = item.recall_id;
                recall.recall_type            = item.recall_type;
                recall.sedol                  = item.sedol;
                recall.status                 = item.status;
                recall.ticker                 = item.ticker;

                recall.groupedTrades.addItem( item.groupedTrades );

                model.recalls.addItem( recall );
            }
```